# specified body CSS width is safe?

Tags: html, css, width

Now very often content with a certain size centered.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #content { margin: auto; width: 960px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="content">Blah!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it safe to not use a wrapper for alignment and size, and apply it directly to a `body` tag? **Like this**:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      body { margin: auto; width: 960px;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   Blah
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just out of interest why would you be wanting to set the `<body>` to the width rather than the `<div>`? The `<div>` can be set to the width and there is very little overhead (if any).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size is safe, however the `margin: auto`-centering isn’t completely.

You have to add `text-align: center` to the body style to center it in IE6, too. (Yeah, I know, it totally makes no sense, but that’s hoe IE6 works)

Comment: IE6 in standards mode supports `margin: auto`. So if you specify a doctype, as you should, `text-align: center` is not necessary.

Comment: Most of us can safely mostly-ignore IE6 at this point.  Maybe just make sure the site is actually usable in IE6, and don't worry about whether it styles the way you want.

Comment: It was IE 5.5 which required the `text-align: center` hack.