# Can I drop the css #wrapper and shift styles to the html tag and the body tag?

Tags: html, css

Can I drop the css #wrapper and shift styles up a level to the html tag and the body tag for a fixed width, centered layout?

```
    html {
        background-color: lightgrey;
        text-align: center;     
    }
    body {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 800px;
        background-color: white;    
        display: block;
    }
```

It seems to be working perfectly well on Firefox, Chrome and IE7+. What are the potential drawbacks?

Comment: what do u intend to gain by doing this? other than removing 2 lines of html?

Comment: That's it. The #wrapper code kinda bugs me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [specified body CSS width is safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986836/specified-body-css-width-is-safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the `<body>` as a wrapper **except** if you're tying to support IE 7 .. due to a peculiar zoom "bug" ..

When a margin or width is applied to the body and the user zooms, IE7 incorrectly treats the left edge of the body as the edge of the viewport. This shift bumps content on the right hand side of the page outside of the screen.

Comment: there are a few drawbacks: http://www.sitepoint.com/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/ ... as long as you account for those quirks you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any drawbacks .. only benefits.  It's now easier for you to override styles on `html` or `body` on other pages by adding a class to them.  I guess it would be a drawback if you *didn't* want to be able to do that (or if you wanted to make it harder).

I'd also advocate for not using IDs in stylesheets at all .. and even elements (i.e. stick to classes and pseudo-classes).  This makes styles for elements easier to update by simply adding and dropping other classes.  Using `html` and `body` is probably okay, though, since there is only ever one of each of those.

Comment: +1 And it's less HTML code which is a good thing, I would say.